# Formik with patch api call in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, formik, patch

i haven't work with rest api and formik so need guidance regarding that.

i have EDIT form where i have one user against id , i want to set user details on form and submit it with updated values and without any error if it kept unchanged.

for this i have to set values of Text Fields somehow and call patch api on submit

this is my form code :

```
 <form  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          >
            <label className="userlabels">Username</label>
            <TextField
              name="userName"
              placeholder="User Name"
              type="text"
              id="userName"
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              value={values.userName}
              onChange={handleChange}
              error={touched.userName && Boolean(errors.userName)}
              helperText={touched.userName && errors.userName}
            
            />

            <label className="userlabels">Fullname</label>
            <TextField
              name="fullName"
              placeholder="Full Name"
              type="text"
              id="fullName"
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              value={values.fullName}
              onChange={handleChange}
              error={touched.fullName && Boolean(errors.fullName)}
              helperText={touched.fullName && errors.fullName}
   
            />

            <label className="userlabels">Email</label>
            <TextField
              name="email"
              placeholder="Email"
              type="email"
              id="email"
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              value={values.email}
              onChange={handleChange}
              error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
              helperText={touched.email && errors.email}
     
            />

            <label className="userlabels">Password</label>
            <TextField
              sx={{
                width: "55%",
                marginBottom: "4vh",
              }}
              name="password"
              placeholder="password"
              type={passwordShown ? "text" : "password"}
              id="password"
              autoComplete="off"
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              value={values.password}
              onChange={handleChange}
              error={touched.password && Boolean(errors.password)}
              helperText={touched.password && errors.password}
            
            />

            <FormControl>
              <label className="userlabels" id="role-label">
                Role
              </label>
              <Select
                name="role"
                labelId="role-label"
                id="role"
                onChange={handleChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
                value={values.role}
                error={touched.role && Boolean(errors.role)}
              >
                {role.map((option, index) => (
                  <MenuItem key={index} value={option.role}>
                    {option.role}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Select>
              <FormHelperText error>
                {touched.role && errors.role}
              </FormHelperText>
            </FormControl>

            <label className="userlabels">Organization</label>
            <TextField
              sx={{
                width: "55%",
                marginBottom: "4vh",
              }}
              name="organ"
              placeholder="Organization"
              type="text"
              id="organ"
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              value={[values.organ]}
              onChange={handleChange}
              error={touched.organ && Boolean(errors.organ)}
              helperText={touched.organ && errors.organ}
              
            />

            <FormControl>
              <label className="userlabels" id="active-label">
                Active
              </label>
              <Select
                name="active"
                labelId="active-label"
                id="active"
                onChange={handleChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
                value={values.active}
                error={touched.active && Boolean(errors.active)}
              >
                {active.map((option, index) => (
                  <MenuItem key={index} value={option.id}>
                    {option.active}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Select>
              <FormHelperText error>
                {touched.active && errors.active}
              </FormHelperText>
            </FormControl>

            <Button
              variant="contained"
              type="submit">
              Update
            </Button>

          </form>
```

and this is formik code

```
const initialValues = {
    fullName: "",
    email: "",
    userName: "",
    organ: [] ,
    password: "",
    role: [],
    active: "",
  };

  const { values, errors, touched, handleBlur, handleChange, handleSubmit } =
    useFormik({
      initialValues,
      validationSchema: UserSchema,
      onSubmit: (values, action) => {
        fetch(`${state.baseUrl}/users/${id}`, {
          method: "PATCH",
          body: JSON.stringify({
            fullname: values.fullName,
            email: values.email,
            username: values.userName,
            organization: [values.organ],
            password: values.password,
            role: [values.role],
            is_active: values.active,
          }),
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
          },
        })
          .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
              setAlert(true);
              setMsg("You Are Successfully Updated the User");
              setType("success");
              return Promise.resolve();
            } else {
              setAlert(true);
              setMsg("Some Thing Went Wrong , Please Try Again Later.");
              setType("error");
              return Promise.reject("failed");
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            setAlert(true);
            setMsg("Some Thing Went Wrong , Please Try Again Later.");
            setType("error");
            console.error("There was an error!", error);
          });

        action.resetForm();
      },
    });
```

i want to get pre-filled form and updated on submission

Comment: It looks like you are doing right with the patch API call for updating. But in order to pre-fill data in edit mode, you need to get data from GET API and then needs to bind it to `initialValues` object.

Comment: In order to handle `initialValues` correctly in case of their change don't forget about `enableReinitialize` option for Formik.

Comment: i was not using `enableReinitialize`